# Browser Tab Manipulation

Tags: javascript, iframe, tabs, reload

Can Someone Please help me? how do you reload an iframe on a page using javascript from another tab opened tab.

example:

i opened a tab, lets say tab1 has an iframe wich is named frame1.

then i open another tab which is tab 2 then a script in tab two will will refresh frame1 in tab1.

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If JavaScript did not open the second page, there is nothing you can do.

If you opened the second tab with JavaScript:

```
var winPop = window.open("foo");
```

and use `winPop` to reference the new window.

```
alert(winPop.getElementsByTagName("div").length);
```

Comment: Im very sorry but i dont understand... im still a newbie into  this... can you just show me a sample code that demonstrate the thing that i want to happen? please...

Comment: `winPop.getElementById("iframeId").location.reload();`